# Animation style CSS to ReactJS style variables

Tags: css, reactjs

I need this CSS line:

```
.anim-typewriter{
     animation: typewriter 2.5s steps(25) 1s 1 normal both,
                blinkTextCursor 650ms steps(25) infinite normal;
}
```

To make it into a ReactJS variable style as I need to change the steps and seconds dynamically depending on the size of the text prop.

Comment: Hey George, styled components might be able to help you there

Answer (score 0):

```
const getAnimationStyle = (duration, steps, blinkCursorDuration) => {
  // returns the css style as a js object
  return {
    animation: `typewriter ${duration}s steps(${steps}) 1s 1 normal both`,
   'blinkTextCursor' : `${blinkCursorDuration}ms steps(${steps}) infinite normal`
  };
}

// set style in element
<div style={getAnimationStyle()}></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, the `blinkTextCursor` you made it like it is a style on its own but it's part of the animation style.